# date picker remains in a fixed place on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a div on a fixed-size scrollable
   `<div style="height:400px; overflow:scroll">`
In div I have an input box with date picker(bootstrap-datepicker)
When scroll the div after opening the date picker,it remains constant in the place where it opened, even though the input box scrolling
http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/EG2TK/4/

Compared to the following situation that I have an input box in a page, when the body scrolling, the datepicker  scrolling with input box
http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/EpKYp/

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: both of those fiddles seem the same to me, do you want the date picker to always be at the top left of the page (visible to user) when the page is scrolled?

Comment: check it now http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/EG2TK/7/

Comment: sorry bud i'm still not understanding your question exactly, what exactly do you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

if you always want the date picker to be in the top left even when the user scrolls set it as a fixed position using CSS. This sets your date picker in the top left corner

```
input {
 position:fixed;
 top: 0; left: 0;/*change position using these*/
}
```